AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'model_endpoint_type' when using Ollama to load local models with MemGPT
I'm trying to use Ollama to load local models with MemGPT, but I'm encountering an AttributeError. Below is the configuration I'm using:
config_list = [
    {
        "model": "NULL",
        "base_url": "http://localhost:11434/v1",
        "api_key": "ollama",
    }
]

config_list_memgpt = [
    {
        "preset": DEFAULT_PRESET,
        "model": "llama3.1",  # only required for Ollama, see: https://memgpt.readme.io/docs/ollama
        "context_window": 8192,  # the context window of your model (for Mistral 7B-based models, it's likely 8192)
        "model_wrapper": "chatml",  # chatml is the default wrapper
        "model_endpoint_type": "ollama",  # can use webui, ollama, llamacpp, etc.
        "model_endpoint": "http://localhost:11434",  # the IP address of your LLM backend
    },
]

When I run the following code, I get an AttributeError:
memgpt_agent = create_memgpt_autogen_agent_from_config(
    "MemGPT_agent",
    llm_config=llm_config_memgpt,
    system_message="You are an AI research assistant.",
    interface_kwargs=interface_kwargs,
    default_auto_reply="...", 
    skip_verify=False,  
)

Error Traceback:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'model_endpoint_type'

The error occurs at this line in the memgpt_agent.py file:
if llm_config["model_endpoint_type"] in ["azure", "openai"] or llm_config["model_endpoint_type"] != config.default_llm_config.model_endpoint_type:
    # Additional code

I've tried different configurations and combinations, but the error persists.
How can I resolve this issue and correctly load the local model using Ollama with MemGPT?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
